# Prove/disprove a propositional statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a homework question that I've been struggling with. I need to prove or disprove that:

$(p ∧ (q ∨ r)) \to (r ∨ (q ∨ p)) = p ∨ q$

I've already constructed the first step of the proof which is

$¬(p ∧ (q ∨ r)) ∨ (r ∨ (q ∨ p)) = p ∨ q$

I really can't form the logic behind this.

Comment: I don't think they are equivalent. If you put $p$ and $q$ with truth value FALSE, then the right hand side has truth value FALSE while the left hand side has truth value TRUE

Answer (score 2):

The LHS always evaluates to TRUE, because whenever the expression to the left of the "implication arrow" is true, $q \lor r$ must be TRUE, and whenever that happens, the expression to the right of the "implication arrow" is also TRUE.

On the other hand, the RHS of the full equality is not always TRUE (for all $p$ and $q$). So the equality doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

If there are not bounds on the method, and you're finding it hard to go with the prepositional boolean algebraic method, then you can go with making truth tables. Since you only have 3 variables here, you just need 8 rows of data, and at most 9 columns to solve it. Compare the columns whose headings are the left, and right hand sides of the equation. If the two columns match, then the prepositions will be equal, otherwise not.